# React Js AWS Amplify PubSub receiving multiple messages

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-iot

I have a react APP that uses the AWS Amplify PubSub library.

I have an IoT device that connect to AWS IoT and publishes message on `topic/pub` (topic).The message is only sent once (from the device) and when I see it in the AWS MQTT client console I can only see only 1 message (as expected) but in the react application I'm receiving multiple messages in the console.

**App.js**

```
...
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react'; // or 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import { withAuthenticator, Button, Heading } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
// Auth.currentCredentials().then(creds => console.log(creds));



function App() {
  return (
      ...

export default withAuthenticator(App,true);
```

**Device Page.js**

```
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './../aws-exports';
import { PubSub } from 'aws-amplify';
import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider({
    aws_pubsub_region: 'xx-xxxxxxx-x',
    aws_pubsub_endpoint: 'wss://<My endpoint from AWS IoT>/mqtt',
   }));


function GaugesComponent  ({id}) {


    PubSub.subscribe('test/pub').subscribe({
        next: data => {
            console.log(data.value);
            

        },
        error: error => console.error(error),
        complete: () => console.log('Done'),
    },);

    return (
    ...

export default GaugesComponent;
```

When my device publishes or I use the AWS MQTT client to publish a message the message is logged multiple times in the console.

**Images:**

AWS MQTT client console

[image: AWS MQTT Console Client]

console log messages of react app

[image: React App Console log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the below code in the device.js where I'm subscribing to the MQTT topic I only added it once in my `app.js` after `Amplify.configure();` like this

**App.js**

```
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider({
    aws_pubsub_region: 'xx-xxxxxxx-x',
    aws_pubsub_endpoint: 'wss://<My endpoint from AWS IoT>/mqtt',
   }));
```

Then I subscribe to the topic using `useEffect()` like this in my device.js

**Device.js**

```
sub_topic = PubSub.subscribe(id+'/live').subscribe({
    next: data => {/*do stuff with received data*/},
    error: error => console.error(error),
    complete: () => console.log('Done'),
},);
return ()=>{
       sub_topic.unsubscribe();
       console.log("Unsubscribed to topic");
    }
},[]);
```